# Biblatex delimiter after journal title

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, delimiters

I am trying to change the separator between the title of a journal article and the following element (In this case the name of the journal).
however, I cannot find the proper delimiter in the §4.10 of the biblatex manual.

For example `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\newline}` inserts a newline after the last author. I tried something similar with `\subtitlepunct`, but it seems to be the wrong delimiter.

Which is the right one? Is there even one?

edit: Some further tests reveal strange behaviour.
If I use `\AtEveryCitekey{\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\newline}}`, then the newline gets added, but before the closing quotation mark of the title
If I try something else, and replace the in:, which definitely comes after the closing quotation with a newline by `\renewbibmacro{in:}{\newline}` the result is even worse, this time both the punctuation and the closing quotation marks come after the newline.

a MWE that illustrates my problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyphenat} 
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
%\AtEveryCitekey{\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\newline}}
%\renewbibmacro{in:}{\newline}
\begin{document}

\fullcite{aksin}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are quite some special punctuation commands, but of course not for all kinds of punctuation in drivers (see §3.9.1 *Generic Commands and Hooks* of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for an overview). The punctuation after the `title` field is not handled significantly different from "normal" ones, that is you have `\newunit` (w/ `\newunitpunct`) and if you have no `language` field (people rarely have these days) also `\newblock` (w/ `\newblockpunct`). ...

Comment: ... You would have to change these to do anything, but this will have knock-on effects on the entire document as `\newunit` and `\newblock` are used extensively throughout `biblatex`'s drivers. Your best bet is probably to change the punctuation after the `title` (maybe even with `\printunit*{<yourpuncthere>}`) with `xpatch`.

Comment: You definitely do not want to make `\newunitpuntc` a `\newline` that will really wreak havoc on your document.

Comment: The trouble is that punctuation is not actually printed and remains in a buffer until it is needed (this buffer can also be overwritten). Also with `american` the punctuation has to go inside the quotation mark, since technically the `\newline` is a punctuation it appears before the closing quotation mark. You could use `\stdpunct` instead disabling this behaviour as in `\AtEveryCitekey{\stdpunctuation\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\newline}}` or `\AtEveryCitekey{\stdpunctuation\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\newline}}`.

Comment: So `[american]` caused  that unexpected behaviour. either your solution, or a change of languages works as expected, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do that with the `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
 }%
 {%
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
}{}{}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{aksin}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I am not very mistaken this is controlled by `\newunitpunct` (or maybe `\newblockpunct`), but redefining those will also change this punctuation at some other places in the entries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It does work in a way, but not correctly. See my edit of the original question.